How to fix the "update(liquibase.Contexts) in liquibase.Liquibase has been deprecated"?
The following function compiles:
    public void deploy(String ldap, String masterChangeLog) throws Exception{
        Database database = getDatabase(ldap);
        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(masterChangeLog, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
        liquibase.update(new Contexts());
    }

but linter generates a deprecation-warning: update(liquibase.Contexts) in liquibase.Liquibase has been deprecated.
The documentation states, one is supposed to use CommandScope, but there are no examples.
Could someone, please, provide one (or two)?

This is, what I ended up with:
import liquibase.Scope;
import liquibase.command.CommandScope;
...
    public void deploy(String ldap, String masterChangeLog)
        throws Exception {
        Database database = getDatabase(ldap);
        Scope.child(Scope.Attr.resourceAccessor,
            new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), () -> {
            CommandScope cmd = new CommandScope("update");
            cmd.addArgumentValue("database", database);
            cmd.addArgumentValue("changelogFile", masterChangeLog);
            cmd.execute();
        });
    }

Note, that passing the database-object as I do above is not documented anywhere -- I guessed it -- but it seems to work. The existing example passes the DB's URL and credentials separately.
Personally, I don't think the λ-notation helps anything here, but that's, how it is in the example...
